# What is the recommended way of sending data from a non web client to a MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to use a java client to send data to my MVC 3 app. The information will only be a bunch of strings such as a username, password hash, etc.

I was thinking of base64 + url encoding a simple XML structure and send it from my client using a Url to my MVC application like so:

```
myapp.com/Post/Add/{endcoded string goes here}
```

This will probably work just fine but what is the best way of passing data into a MVC application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you using standard HTTP protocol stuff. For example a POST verb with content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works just great, or you could even use `multipart/form-data`:

On the ASP.NET MVC side you would have a controller action accepting a view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...    
}
```

And finally you would write a custom model binder which would read the XML from the request and deserialize it back to your view model.

I would recommend you avoiding custom stuff, wheel and protocol reinvention as much as possible (such as base64 encoding of parameters).

As far as the client side is concerned, my last Java experience is dating back to 2003 so I cannot exactly tell you how to create an HTTP Java client but I am more than persuaded that it should be an [easy task](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/).